# Facebook login issue with nodejs passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, passport.js

My generated URL : https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-52-87-141-161.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=1861989877370748

My developer console looks like:
[image]

But I am still getting error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it all wrong. With new console, we need to specify login redirect url in Left Panel :

> **Products > Facebook Login > Settings > Valid OAuth redirect URIs**

If you are not able to find it, then you can directly access it from following URL.

> https://developers.facebook.com/apps/**APPID**/fb-login/
>
> Note: In above URL **APPID** is your Facebook app id

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your public dns as your site's url, not even your public ip. Get a domain, point it the public ip (or public dns, if you wish) and then try adding the site url to the developer console. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/auth/facebook/callback` from site url. Just use the base url. Furthermore, add the same base url and callback url in the whitelist input box in your advanced section tab.